# Getting all the keys of a map of the form <pair<int,int>, int*> in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

In my C++ code I am using a map like this:

```
std::map<std::pair<int,int>,int*> patterns;
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how I get all the keys of that map which are of the form

```
pair<int,int>
```

I have seen a few questions related to it, but in all the cases keys are single integers.

Comment: Are you trying to iterate through the list of keys contained in the map? This seems like a strange way to use `std::map`.

Comment: Yeah I know. But to solve the problem I did not find any other better data structure to use. No I just want to have the keys of the map in sorted order.

Comment: @Joy, are you trying to iterate through the keys of the map, or are you trying to make a new container that contains all the keys in the map?

Comment: @BrianBi, I just want to access the map in sorted order of the keys. That's why I thought I first collect the keys in sorted order in another array or vector and then access the values of map. If I am wrong, please rectify.

Comment: @Joy: you can just iterate through the map by reference, without copying all the keys into another container. See the first two snippets of code in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to just iterate through all the keys:

**C++03**

```
for (std::map<std::pair<int,int>,int*>::iterator I = patterns.begin(); I != patterns.end(); I++) {
    // I->first is a const reference to a std::pair<int,int> stored in the map
}
```

**C++11**

```
for (auto& kv : patterns) {
    // kv.first is a const reference to a std::pair<int,int> stored in the map
}
```

If you wanted to copy the keys into a new container:

**C++03**

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > V;
std::set<std::pair<int,int> > S;
for (std::map<std::pair<int,int>,int*>::iterator I = patterns.begin(); I != patterns.end(); I++) {
    V.push_back(I->first);
    S.insert(I->first);
}
```

**C++11**

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> V;
std::set<std::pair<int,int>> S;
for (auto& kv : patterns) {
    V.push_back(kv.first);
    S.insert(kv.first);
}
```

Because I'm bored, here are a few additional solutions:

You could also do it with standard algorithms and a lambda function, but I don't think this is really better than just writing the loop yourself:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> V(patterns.size());
std::transform(patterns.begin(), patterns.end(), V.begin(),
               [](decltype(patterns)::value_type& p){ return p.first; });

std::set<std::pair<int,int>> S;
std::for_each(patterns.begin(), patterns.end(),
              [&S](decltype(patterns)::value_type& p){ S.insert(p.first); });
```

You could also use a Boost transform iterator to wrap iterators from the map, such that when the wrapped iterator is dereferenced, it gives you just the key from the map. Then you could call `std::vector::insert` or `std::set::insert` directly on a range of transform iterators.

Comment: This would work for iterating through the map but I don't think that's what he's trying to do.

Comment: @JeremyVillegas ooh, yeah, you're right, I may have misinterpreted the question. :/

Comment: To get all the keys there's no option but to iterate over the map.